# Is it possible to use styled (e.g., colored) text in PlotLabel?

Tags: plotting, legending

Sometimes, I want to provide a key or legend for my `Plot` or `ListPlot` without using the `PlotLegends` package.  Sometimes, I just want to use the option `PlotLabel` inside my `Plot` or `ListPlot`:

```
Plot[{x^2, x^3}, {x,0,10}, PlotStyle->{Red, Blue}, 
    PlotLabel->"Red curve: x^2\nBlue curve: x^3"]
```

Is there any way to actually make the string `"Red curve: x^2"` red and the string `"Blue curve: x^3"` blue, within `PlotLabel`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, use `Style` and `Column` to format the `PlotLabel`:

```
PlotLabel -> Column[{Style["Red curve: x^2", Red], Style["Blue curve: x^3", Blue]}]]
```

**Example:**
[image]